# Call actionPerformed of a JTextField using its object

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, actionevent, javax

I have a `javax.swing.JTextField` named ***SearchBox*** with an actionPerformed Event.

```
public void SearchBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
     //TODO
}
```

What I want to do is to call the above method from another method in a different class by passing the `JTextField` object as an argument.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Program {

    public static synchronized void QuickSearchResults(JTextField textBox) {
        /*
         * I want to call ActionPerformed method of textBox if it has any.
         */
    }
}
```

> Please note that calling the method name directly is not an option. If
>   I pass 3 different `JTextField` objects, the relevant ActionPerformed
>   methods should be called.

Is there a way to achieve this? I already tried using,

```
textBox.getActions();
textBox.getActionListeners();
```

but it didn't go well, and now I'm back in square one.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: You can't call private method from another class. To receive `ActionEvent` JTextField must use `addActionListener` to add `ActionListener`

Comment: @JaySmith ActionEvent is working perfectly when I press enter. I just added the summary.

Comment: Even if I make the method Public, how can i use the `JTextField` object to call it?

Comment: If you use JTextField, you can call only its methods.

Comment: You can call `SearchBoxActionPerformed` method from `actionPerformed` of `ActionListener` which you added to jtextfield

Comment: `JTextField` doesn't have `actionPerformed` method and you can'r call it and you can't get ActionEvent other than in `ActionListener`

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but your need to construct your own ActionEvent if you wanted to call that method

Comment: `JTextField#postActionEvent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTextField#postActionEvent` will trigger the fields `ActionListener`s, which is what I assume you're trying to do

```
public class Program {

    public static synchronized void QuickSearchResults(JTextField textBox) {
        textBox.postActionEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. But this calls all actionEvents connected with the JTextField. Is there is a way to call a specific one?

Comment: Not really how it's suppose to work, I mean, how would identify the particular listener you're interested in? You could have a look at getActionListeners, but you're still going to have to generate your own ActionEvent. Without more information, I'd suggest investigating the Action API

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to achieve this, but it's certainly not the best.

```
public static synchronized void QuickSearchResults(JTextField textBox) {
    ActionListener actions[] = textBox.getActionListeners();
    for (ActionListener x : actions) {
        x.actionPerformed(null);
    }
}
```

In this case, only the `ActionListener`s are being called, but all of them which have been added to the `JTextField` using `addActionListener(ActionListener l)`.

As I have said above, this may not be the best way, but solves the problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it only triggers the ActionListeners (I checked the source before posting) in fact, what you've done in your loop, is what I did with postActionEvent - passing null as the ActionEvent is I'll advised, as no will expect it, as we're all use to getting a non-null value

Comment: @MadProgrammer It does call most of the `EventListener`s for sure. try adding more events using, `addFocusListener(FocusListener l)`, `addKeyListener(KeyListener l)`. Like `keyReleased` or `focusLost` events...

Comment: No, it doesn't, all it does is calls fireActionPerformed, maybe you're thinking postEvent? Why would it trigger a focus lost event?

Comment: So, I created a test with a field add a button, I attached a ActionListener, MouseListener, FocusListener and KeyListener, I called postActionEvent when the button was clicked ... and ... only the ActionListener was notified

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
public static synchronized void QuickSearchResults(JTextField textBox) {
    /*
     * I want to call ActionPerformed method of textBox if it has any.
     */
    textBox.addActionListener(e->{
        //Do what you want
    });
}
```

Comment: Adding a new `ActionListener` is not going to help. Because the codes in actionPerformed methods will differ from `JtextField` to `JtextField`. I need to call the specific actionPerformed event of the  `JtextField` passed.